# Traceback.extract_stack(); from Python to C#?

Tags: c#, python

```
                // m3 = traceback.extract_stack();
                StackTrace st = new StackTrace(true);  // replace m3

                log.Log(String.Format("{0}  - Stack Trace", msg));

                log.Log(String.Format("{0,-40}  {1,-15}  {2,7}", "File (partial path)", "Method", "Line No."));

                string file = st.GetFrame(1).GetFileName();
                if (file != null)
                {
                    if (file.Length > 40)
                    {
                        string f = file.Substring(file.Length - 40); // last 40 characters 
                        //string f = file.Substring(0, Math.Min(40, file.Length));  // This is the first 40 characters
                        log.Log(String.Format("{0,-40}  {1,-15}  {2,7}", f, st.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().Name, st.GetFrame(1).GetFileLineNumber()));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        log.Log(String.Format("{0,-40}  {1,-15}  {2,7}", file, st.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().Name, st.GetFrame(1).GetFileLineNumber()));
                    }
                }
```

I'm curious as to how I could do a traceback.extract_stack() in C# then I can create a foreach loop to cycle through the traceback. Instead of just printing out the single method, partial file, and line number. Also, is there a way to print the statement and function instead of just the method in C#?

Comment: You need to provide more context here. What does `traceback.extract_stack()` refer to (i.e. is it from the built-in libraries or is it from another library you have imported, if so which one?) Why does your question mention Python? It isn't clear. Also overall what are you trying to accomplish? A quick summary of what the entire program does would help.

Comment: It's related to stacktrace or at least that's what I got out of it (new programmer). But the way its currently working shows just the function that called the function. traceback.extract_stack() - Extract the raw traceback from the current stack frame. The return value has the same format as for extract_tb(). The optional f and limit arguments have the same meaning as for print_stack(). I'm learning right now c# but my job at work is to make a python program work as a c# template. This line of his code m3 = traceback.extract_stack() I don't get how it can be done in c# I only know stacktrace.

Comment: So, long story short I want to know how I can create the line m3 = traceback.extract_stack(); in c#.